# Count good numbers that are multiple of 7 upto M

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, algorithms

Given a number of $N$ digits with $A[1]$ denoting the first digit , $A[2]$ second digit and $A[n]$ last digit from left to right. It is called good number if

```
A[1]^N + A[2]^(N-1) + A[N]^1 is divisible by 7.
```

Like if its $abcd$ then $a^4 + b^3 + c^2 + d$ must be divisible by 7

Now given $M$ we need to count all the good numbers less than $M$. But $M$ can go up to 10^9. So some fast solution is required for it.

**Example** : Let $N=7$ Then answer is $1$ as Up to number $7$ only $7^1$ is an good number. So the answer is $1$.

How to do it for given M ?

Comment: Please do a little self-research on this problem. In particular, find a couple of more good numbers besides the trivial one you've written above ($7$), and add them to your question. It will help other readers, and it might even help you to detect a pattern and find the answer yourself.

Comment: @barakmanos I know that for M=9999 answer is 1388

Comment: That's just throwing some piece of information you got somewhere. It doesn't tell us anything about any good number smaller than $9999$, only that there are $1388$ such numbers. I would not consider that as anything close to self-research, unless you could provide at least some of those $1388$ numbers.

Comment: @barakmanos Few starting good numbers are : 7,16,23,35,45..

Comment: OK, that's a good start. What about $3$-digit numbers?

Comment: @barakmanos 106,115,122,134 are few starting good numbers in 3 digit

Comment: Is this yet another problem from codechef ?